# Inner product between matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

The standard inner product between matrices is often chosen to be
\begin{align}
\langle A,B\rangle=\mathrm{tr}(AB^\intercal)\,.
\end{align}
I would like to define another product that looks for $3\times 3$-matrices like the following. We define the operator $\hat{\alpha}$ (where $\alpha$ is a positive real number) acting on matrices, such that
\begin{align}
A=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}\\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23}\\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}
\end{array}
\right)\,,\qquad \hat{\alpha}(A)=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
a_{11} & \alpha a_{12} &\alpha^2  a_{13}\\
\alpha a_{21} & a_{22} & \alpha a_{23}\\
\alpha^2 a_{31} & \alpha a_{32} & a_{33}
\end{array}\right)
\end{align}
and define the new inner product as
\begin{align}
\langle A,B\rangle=\mathrm{tr}\left(\hat{\alpha}(A)\hat{\alpha(B)}^\intercal\right)\,.
\end{align}
Is there another elegant way to express this product? In general, can I represent any inner product between matrices in a similar way to the Frobenius product with traces?

In other words, my inner product is such that the matrices $M(x,y)_{ij}=\delta_{xi}\delta_{yj}$ form an orthonormal basis with norms $\lVert M(x,y)\rVert=\alpha^{|x-y|}$.

Answer (score 2):

I think that your way to expres is elegant enough, but you could use, if you want, the property

$$
tr(\hat \alpha(A) \hat\alpha(B)^T)  = tr(\hat\alpha(\hat\alpha(A))B^T)=tr(A \hat\alpha(\hat\alpha(B))^T)
$$

Comment: I guess, I'm looking for a more basis-independent way. Initially, I hoped to write something like $\mathrm{tr}(AC_\alpha B^\intercal)$ or something similar. I can't express $\hat{\alpha}$ as an elegant linear map, such as $\hat{\alpha}=C_{\alpha}\cdot A$ or similar...

Comment: you can use the Hadamard product for that

Comment: I see - I guess, I can't simplify it further then - thank you!